# How to find trailing and leading words of a word using R?

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a text document which has a million words. Now, I need to know how to find trailing and leading words of a word using R.

For example, If I want to find out the words that are coming before and after the word "error". It could be anything like following with leading words

```
"typo error"
"manual error"
"system error"
```

and with trailing words like

```
"error corrected"
"error found"
"error occurred"
```

Any idea how to do this? Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For words coming before error:

```
x <- "no error and no error and some error" # input

library(gsubfn)
rx <- "(\\w+) error"
table(strapplyc(x, rx)[[1]])
```

giving:

```
  no some 
   2    1
```

Replace `rx` with the following for words after error:

```
rx <- "error (\\w+)"
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be `str_match_all`:

```
library(stringr)
txt <- "system error corrected hardcore error detected wtf error holymoly"
str_match_all(txt, "\\s*(\\w+)\\serror\\s*(\\w+)")

[[1]] 
     [,1]                       [,2]       [,3]        
[1,] "system error corrected"   "system"   "corrected" 
[2,] " hardcore error detected" "hardcore" "detected"  
[3,] " wtf error holymoly"      "wtf" "holymoly"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
test <- c("I don't want to match error this This is a random error what I want to match")
# convert to a list  
words <- strsplit((test),' ')
# get indexes that match 'error' 
indexes <-   grep('error',words[[1]], perl=TRUE)

# select words that come after 'error'
words[[1]][indexes+1]
# before 'error'
words[[1]][indexes-1]
```